# Creating a Reverse Polish calculator in C++

Tags: c++, polish-notation

**Assignment**: For this assignment, you are to write a program, which will calculate the results of Reverse Polish expressions that are provided by the user.

You must handle the following situations (errors):

Too many operators (+ - / *)

Too many operands (doubles)

Division by zero

The program will take in a Polish expression that separates the operators and operands by a single space, and terminates the expression with an equals sign.

The program will continue to take and evaluate expressions until the user enters a zero (0) on a line by itself followed by a new line.

> **Problem 1:**  I am having a problem with telling the user that there are too many operators and operands. I tried to code it but I have no
>   idea where to begin with this.
>
> **Problem 2:** I want the program to end when the user inputs 0, but it is not doing anything when I do it in my program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    double data;
    Node *top;
    Node *ptr;
public:
    Node()
    {
        top = NULL;
        ptr = NULL;
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        return top == 0;
    }

    void pushValue(double val)
    {
        Node *next = new Node;
        next->data = val;
        next->ptr = top;
        top = next;
    }

    double popVal()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            cout << "Error: Too many operators" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            Node *next = top->ptr;
            double ret = top->data;
            delete top;
            top = next;
            return ret;
        }

    }
//Displays the answer of the equation
    void print()
    {
        cout << "= " << top->data << endl;
    }
};

bool isOperator(const string& input)
{
    string ops[] = { "+", "-", "*", "/" };
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (input == ops[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
//This function tells the operators what to do with the values.
void performOp(const string& input, Node& stack)
{
    double Val1, Val2;
    int errorCheck = 0;

    Val1 = stack.popVal();
    Val2 = stack.popVal();

    if (input == "+")
    {
        stack.pushValue(Val1 + Val2);
    }
    else if (input == "-")
    {
        stack.pushValue(Val1 - Val2);
    }
    else if (input == "*")
    {
        stack.pushValue(Val1 * Val2);
    }
    else if (input == "/" && Val2 != 0)
    {
        stack.pushValue(Val1 / Val2);
    }

    if (input == "/" && Val2 == 0)
    {
        cout << "Error: Division by zero" << endl;
        errorCheck = 1;
    }

    if (errorCheck == 0)
    {
        stack.print();
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Reverse Polish Notation Calculator!" << endl;
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your values followed by your operators(Enter 0 to exit)" << endl;

    string input;
    Node stack;
//Checks the user's input to see which function to use.
    while (true)
    {
        cin >> input;
        double num;

        if (stringstream(input) >> num)
        {
            stack.pushValue(num);
        }
        else if (isOperator(input))
        {
            performOp(input, stack);
        }
        else if (input == "0")
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your input of "0" gets caught by the first if - it is used to set num to zero.

Comment: @H.Guijt so how would i fix that? I am still kinda confused

Comment: Your first if-statement in the while-true loop tests for any kind of number. Since zero is a valid number, that block of code is executed, and the later one (which ends the program) is skipped. The easiest way is to use another input for quitting the program; you could use a character like 'q', for example (or anything that is not itself a valid number or operator).

Comment: @H.guijt i originally did that but the professor wanted specifically the number 0 to stop the program. Any ideas on how i can have it stop the program and allow users to input like 9 0 / without the program stopping? thanks again!

Comment: Can you really not figure this out on your own? Look at the order in which the tests occur. The test for "all numbers" is currently the first one, while the test for zero is at the end. Take it from there.